DeploymentScriptOperationFailed when running Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts
We've been using Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts for about a year now and never had any issues. To run script, we are using User Managed Identity. No changes to the template were made from our side. Recently we started seeing this error
{"code":"DeploymentScriptOperationFailed","message":"Resource '23fl75rmqngz2azscripts' was disallowed by policy. Reasons: 'Shared Storage Access Keys are not allowed'. See error details for policy resource IDs."}
Looks like it tries to connect to storage account using Storage Access Keys but they are not allowed.
The Storage Settings in Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts template consist only from name and key.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deploymentscripts?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template#storageaccountconfiguration-1
Can you please help with workaround/solution?

Can you share the code tried so far! @Albert Samigullin

Turned out my colleague enforced this policy. Our team is unblocked.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
